# Hide Subscriber tab in Salesforce CRM Library Content

Tags: content

I want to hide the Subscriber Tab in Salesforce CRM Content. Which effectively means that the user is still able to Subscribe to the content by clicking the button on the top but does not see who else has subscribed to the document.
Is there any way to turn it off?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

In  our community we found a way to hid the subscriber tab by including some lines in our HTML footer. Below is an example of what we included in the HTML footer to hide the subscribers and Comments tabs:

```
<style type="text/css">our    
div.x-tab-strip-wrap {display:none;}
</style>
```

I have created an idea on the IdeaExchange for this same request - 
[Hide Subscribers tab on content for portal and community users](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E2bYQAS)